# Simple jQuery Fading Sequence problem

Tags: jquery

I'm looking for a little help with my jQuery fading sequence.

My Code:

```
$('#1').fadeOut('fast');
$('#1same').fadeOut('fast');
$('#fadeinme').fadeIn('slow');
```

I'm looking to add a 1 second delay after the first 2 (#1 & #1same fade out at the same time) before the 3rd fades in.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use the `completed` callback to execute the `fadeIn` after the first animation has completed, then use [`.delay`](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) to add the one second delay:

```
$('#1, #1same').fadeOut('fast', function(){
    $('#fadeinme').delay(1000).fadeIn('slow');
});
```

Do note that in HTML4, `id`s cannot start with a number.

Comment: @Alexwhin I misread your question initially, I think *this* should work now