# jQuery premature fade in

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, opacity, fade

I am trying to make a set of square divs (".block") fade out when one is clicked, to be replaced by a larger div ("#container"), which fades in as soon as they fade out. This works fine:

```
$('.block').animate({opacity:0},400,'swing',function(){ $('#container').fadeIn();});
```

I use "animate" here because I don't want the space occupied by the blocks to collapse when they fade out (which would happen if I used fadeOut).

The '#container' div has a close button, which when clicked is supposed to fade out the container and fade the blocks back in again. Here's the problem: when the close button is clicked, the container fades out ok, but the new blocks appear very suddenly, as if they're not waiting for the container to close first. Code:

```
$('#container').fadeOut(400,function(){ $('.block').animate({opacity:100},400,'swing');});
```

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4981608/simple-jquery-fading-sequence-problem) suggests adding delay -- for me all this does is fade out the container, then wait a second, then quickly (too quickly) bring the blocks back.

Any ideas why this isn't working much appreciated.

Comment: I'm surprised that you say your first line works - you have a syntax-error in the callback-function. The code-highlight indicates it. You use a single-quote at the beginning of the selector and a double-quote at the end of selector.

Comment: Well spotted, but that just occurred in my transcription (I edited the code slightly for this question). I'll edit my question to amend the error.

Comment: btw, the css opacity accepts values from 0 to 1

Comment: Beautiful, that solved it. Stupid mistake. Thanks! If there's a way to mark this as a correct answer please let me know and I will do so.

Comment: I'll write one up real quick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSS opacity accepts values from 0 to 1.

```
$('#container').click(function () {
    $(this).fadeOut(400, function () {
        $('.block').animate({
            opacity: 1 //was 100
        }, 400, 'swing');
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/WEhCc/1/